# jquery mobile splash screen with javascript

Tags: jquery-mobile, splash-screen

I'm seeking to avoid using this for the splash screen, because it does not work on all devices and for other reasons:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash.png" />
```

So I'm trying to use this instead and it works fine until it slides into a new page, which is then treated like the splash screen again (e.g. **it goes blank when the timer expires - in this case 4 seconds**). How can I stop/restrict this behavior, so that changePage remains contained in splash page only?

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="splash"> 
  <div class="splash">
    <img src="startup.jpg" alt="startup image" />

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
            $(window).load(function(){
            $(function() {
                setTimeout(hideSplash, 4000);
                        });

            function hideSplash() {
            $.mobile.changePage("#home", "fade");
            }


            });//]]>  
        </script>

  </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
   <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1></h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">

   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9):

Good idea here is what I'm thinking. Use single pages instead of multi page(multiple data-role=page). For index.html or index.php or whatever. Put your splash page. The reason for this I will explain later on.

> index.html

```
<head>
    <!-- First include all jquery stuff -->
    <script src="app.js"></script><!-- external script because we can just include it in every page -->
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="splash"> 
        <div class="splash">
            <img src="startup.jpg" alt="startup image" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

> app.js

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#splash',function(){ // the .on() method does require jQuery 1.7 + but this will allow you to have the contained code only run when the #splash page is initialized.
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("home.html", "fade");
    }, 4000);
});
```

Ok so I did it this way because lets say you have navigation menu and you want to send people back to home page. You won't have to show the splash page again. You can just link to home.html. Also splitting up your pages helps keep the dom leaner. I hope this helps.

Comment: Works well with a single page too

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash.png" />
```

Is indeed only for apple mobile devices.

A real splashscreen should only be there to show you a nice picture *while* you're waiting. Its goal is not to make you wait for real reason. In your case it's taking 4seconds out of the life of your users just to make it look cool.

I have modified your code and put it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7ZRr/) : you'll see it works now. For the splashscreen to take the full width/height edit the css to remove the margins. I've set the timer to 2s, that's more than enough I think.

Comment: That 4 seconds though would be great from a branding standpoint and also to make you web app feel slightly more native. Oh and btw the .live() method is deprecated. There are a number of known issues with it. See http://api.jquery.com/live/