# jQuery Mobile Splash Screen Keeps Reloading in Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, safari

I'm working on adding a splash page to a mobile web app.  I want the logo page to display while the site is loading...  about 4 seconds.  I have the below code working fine in all browsers except Safari.  In Safari, the page keeps reloading every 4 seconds.  I tried using a Meta tag, with the same result in Safari only.  Any ideas greatly appreciated!

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
  $('#splash').live('pageshow', function(){
       var hideSplash = function() {
           $.mobile.changePage($("#home"));
       };
      setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000);
  });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="splash">
            <div data-role="content">  
                <img src="http://www.intergrupo.net/blog/wp-content/plugins/wptouch-pro/themes/classic/iphone/images/retina/retina-startup.png" alt="startup image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
                <h1>New page!!</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
       New content!<br/>
       Test!!
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh...  this code came from a previous thread:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763583/jquery-mobile-splash-screen-with-javascript

Comment: Do you need to use your function inside of `$('#splash').live('pageshow', function(){
` instead of `$(function() {` ?

Comment: Got it figured out....   I had this statement in my head>>>                        <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;URL='#page'" />