# Splash screen in Jquery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, screen, splash-screen

So I tried to make a splash screen based on the answer codaniel gave on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763583/jquery-mobile-splash-screen-with-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top). Thing is that I can't make it work proporly. First of all, if I integrate the splash screen in a single page and link it to a multipage, it keeps linking to the single page (even though I changed the link correctly). Secondly the splash screen bugs when it goes to the linked page. Anyone who has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to use the [splashscreen](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html) of cordova itself.

Comment: I tried that, but my image wasn't in proportion, even though I used the widths & heights in the documentation. I suppose this depends on the device, but isn't this a bit iffy to trust on?

Comment: No it isn't. You normally create a splashscreen in different sizes and resolution (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi) so the correct proportion and format is choosen automatically by the app. You can find the default splashscreens under project/res/drawable-XXXX in your eclipse cordova project. ;)

Comment: I know, I did use the dimensions in the documentation and placed it in the drawable maps. I tested it with a Huawei Ideos S7 Slim and the splashscreen was totally out of proportion.

Comment: For me it worked with a lot of different android smartphones... did you tried it already on the simulator?

Comment: The emulator doesn't work on my pc, so I can only test on tablets or phones.

Comment: Maybe you give the cordova splash screen a second try on a different tablet/phone?

Comment: Isn't that an easy solution to a difficult problem? Even though it might look good on another tablet or phone, I know that it doesn't on all devices. Isn't the goal of developing making sure the design looks good on all devices?